# Time Code in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a code that calls the system time and updates it every minute. Can anybody give me an example that will steer me in the right direction? thanks

Comment: Date now = new Date() will get the system time :)

Comment: Updates the system time, or an internal timer to the software?

Comment: The OS takes care of this? I don't think you should screw with the system time like that.

Comment: Later duplicate: [Java timer to make a function run every minute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23445137/642706) and [Running a Java Thread in intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/426758/642706)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you're looking for a [`Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). It can schedule a task such as updating anything every minute.

---

```
public class MyScheduledTask extends TimerTask{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Message printed every minute");
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String... args){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MyScheduledTask(), 0, 60*1000);
        //Do something that takes time 
    }
}
```

---

For the current system time you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

---

**Resources :**

- [javadoc - Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)
- [javadoc - System.currentTimeMillis()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())

Comment: i see that i would need a timer but wouldn't i need a counter also in order for the time to update every minute

Comment: The timer.schedule count itself, the `60*1000` argument says it will call the `run()` method of `MyScheduledTask` every 60*1000 milliseconds.

Comment: import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class CAARSCounter_1 extends TimerTask{

  public void run(){
        System.out.println("Message printed every minute");}
    
public static void currentTimeMillis(){
}
 
  public void main(String... args){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new CAARSCounter_1(),0 , 60*1000);}
}

Comment: You don't have to define your own `currentTimeMillis()`. But it's about right.

Comment: Edit your question and put this code in it, and mark it as code so it doesn't wrap like this.

Comment: I seem to have a plethora of questions lol but, how would i get the time to print to the screen every minute

Comment: You can use either `Date now = new Date()` as suggested in comments and print it or `currentTimeMillis()` to get the currentTime as a long.

Answer (score 1):

If you were just looking to create a timer you could create a Thread to execute every second within an infinite loop

```
public class SystemTime extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while (true){
            String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

            System.out.println(time);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie){
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```