# MultiThreads: can we make one thread as daemon thread, and execute thread status detection on other theads every 5 mins

Tags: java, multithreading

Just as mentioned, can we make one thread as daemon thread, and execute some detection codes on detecting other threads status? i hope the daemon thread will be executed every 5 mins(more or less, inaccuracy can't be huge, several seconds delay are acceptable)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426758/running-a-java-thread-in-intervals

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor svc = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, new ThreadFactory() {

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
            t1.setDaemon(true);
            return t1;
        }
    });

    svc.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Himanshu "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    svc.awaitTermination(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426758/running-a-java-thread-in-intervals) first, like @Azodious said. The job you want to schedule is using `ThreadMXBean`s. See sample core [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/profiling/profiling_java5_threads_howto.shtml).