# The right way, to continuously query a Modbus in Java (JAMOD)

Tags: java, modbus-tcp

I wanted to ask how to query every second Modbus, using the JAMOD library.
Decided to make a preliminary connection to Modbus and then, within a loop while(true) query the Modbus. After interrogating the device, use a Thread.sleep (1000); is the right way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `Thread` (something that `implements Runnable`).

See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/426795/362332

Answer (score 0):

```
//I usually use asynchronous threads to process
//example
@Async
public Future<Integer> loop() {
    while (true) {
        int value = modbusServer.read(1001);
        if (value == 1) {
            //Business processing ...

            break;
        }
        thread.sleep(50);
    }
    return new AsyncResult(1);
}
```